# Evaluate $\int^{2}_{0}\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{1+4x}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $\displaystyle \int^{2}_{0}\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{1+4x}\mathrm dx$

My effort:

\begin{align*}
I(a)&=\int^{2}_{0}\frac{\tan^{-1}(ax)}{1+4x}\mathrm dx\\
I'(a) &= \int^{2}_{0}\frac{x}{(1+4x)(1+a^2x^2)}\mathrm dx\\
I'(a) &= \frac{1}{4}\int^{2}_{0}\frac{(1+4x)-1}{(1+4x)(1+a^2x^2)}dx\\
I'(a) &= \frac{1}{4a}\tan^{-1}(2)-\frac{1}{4}\int^{2}_{0}\frac{1}{(1+4x)(1+a^2x^2)}dx
\end{align*}

Then how to proceed? Thank you.

Comment: Partial Fraction Decomposition?

Comment: @ mrtaurho i searcing for some easy way to handle that problem but not find it.have any idea please help me thanks

Comment: From where did you get this integral? Is it worth hoping an elementary answer?

Comment: What is $tan^{-1}$? Is it $arctan$ or $cot$?

Comment: @Hume2: By looking at the formula of $I'(a)$ it is clear that we are talking about $\arctan$. Plus, if it were $\cot$, the integral would be divergent towards $0$.

Comment: You can use the general formula which I've used for my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164280/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-h-2n-h-n-ln2) . In my answer for your question I've set $n=1$. Your question is a special case of it (as I've shown below).

Comment: Thank you for awards!  There were a creative command, and my proposition is to continue the competition in the new question - to  express the integral $\int_0^p \dfrac{\arctan x}{1+qx}\,dx$ in the elementary functions.

Comment: @user90369 Can you get the closed form of the integral $\int_0^p \dfrac{\arctan x}{1+qx}\,dx$ in the elementary functions?

Comment: I've meant the closed form, and I guess the interesting battle.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov : If you mean a closed form *including* polylogarithms then please simply use the formula (for the indefinite integral) of my answer here ($q$ instead of $4$). More general is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164280/evaluate-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-h-2n-h-n-ln2), please have a look also at the *hint* in my answer there for $\frac{1}{n!}\int\frac{(\ln(x+z))^n}{(x-a)^{m+1}}dx $ . ;)

Comment: @user90369 Integral via polylogarithm is computed in my answer. I mean the closed form in the elementary function (with arbitrary constants). I have not it yet, but I hope to obtain it.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov : So, looking at your solution, you like to know $\,\displaystyle \Im \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{1+pt}{1-ip}\right)\,$ in a (real) closed form ? I do not know that and therefore I've used *series* $A$ and $B$ to give a complete answer here.

Comment: @user90369 The common solution looks impossible, but such special cases exist.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov : Special cases, yes. We can find out such things by using the (existing) function equations for polylogarithms. But with the parameter $\frac{1+pt}{1-ip}$ ? That doesn't look very special, because $p$ and $t$ are variable. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Another way to obtain result.*

Are known trigonometric equalities

> $$\tan(a+b) = \dfrac{\tan a+\tan b}{1-\tan a\tan b},\tag{Q1}$$
>   $$\tan\left(a+\frac\pi4\right) = \dfrac{\tan a +1}{1-\tan a},\tag{Q2}$$
>   $$\sec^2\left(a+\frac\pi4\right) = 2\dfrac{1+\tan^2a}{(1-\tan a)^2}.\tag{Q3}$$

Let $\,x= \tan (y+\frac\pi4),\quad dx=\sec^2(y+\frac\pi4)\,dy,\,$ then

\begin{align}
&I(1) = \int\limits_0^2 \dfrac{\frac\pi4+\arctan x-\frac\pi4}{1+4x}\,dx 
 = \dfrac\pi4\int\limits_0^2 \dfrac{dx}{1+4x}
 + \int\limits_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan\frac13} \dfrac {y\sec^2(y+\frac\pi4)\,dy}{1+4\tan(y+\frac\pi4)}\\ 
& = \dfrac\pi{16}\ln(1+4x)\bigg|_0^2
 + \int\limits_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}\dfrac{2(1+\tan^2y)y\,dy} {(1-\tan y)^2\left(1+4\frac{\large\tan y+1}{\large1-\tan y}\right)}\\
& = \dfrac{\pi\ln3}8
 + \int\limits_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}
\dfrac{2y\sec^2y\,dy}{(1-\tan y)(5+3\tan y)}\\
& = \dfrac{\pi\ln3}8 + \dfrac14\int\limits_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}
y\left(\dfrac1{1-\tan y}+\dfrac3{5+3\tan y}\right)\sec^2y\,dy\\
& = \dfrac{\pi\ln3}8 
+ \dfrac14\int\limits_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}
y\,d\ln\dfrac{5+3\tan y}{1-\tan y}\\
& = \dfrac{\pi\ln3}8 + \dfrac y4\,\ln\dfrac{5+3\tan y}{1-\tan y}
\Bigg|_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}
 - \dfrac14\int\limits_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}
\ln\dfrac{5+3\tan y}{1-\tan y}\,dy\\
& = \dfrac{\pi\ln3}8 + \dfrac{\dfrac\pi2-\arctan3}2\ \ln3
- \dfrac{\dfrac\pi2-\arctan3+\dfrac\pi4}4\ \ln5
 - \dfrac14\int\limits_{\large-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}
\ln\dfrac{1+\dfrac35\tan y}{1-\tan y}\,dy,\\
\end{align}
$$I(1) = \dfrac{3\pi - 4\arctan3}{16}\ \ln\dfrac95
 - \dfrac14 J(p,y)\Bigg|_{\large y=-\frac\pi4}^{\large\arctan \frac13}
\Bigg|_{\large p=-1}^{\large\frac35},\tag1$$

where
$$J(p,y) = \int\,\ln(1+p\tan y)\,dy,\tag2$$
$$|p|\le 1,\quad |\tan y| \le1,\tag3$$

\begin{align}
&J(p,y) = \dfrac i2 \left(\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{1+p\tan y}{1-ip}\right) 
- \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{1+p\tan y}{1+ip}\right)\right)\\
& + \dfrac i2\left(\ln\dfrac{1-i\tan y}{-1+ip}-\ln\dfrac{1+i\tan y}{-1-ip}\right) \ln(1+p\tan y) + \mathrm{constant}
\end{align}
(see also [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%20ln(1%2Bp%20tan%20y)%20dy)),

> $$\ \operatorname {Li}_2(z) = \sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty\dfrac{z^j}{j^2}\tag{Q4}$$

is the [polylogarithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html).

Is known that

> $$\ln a = \ln|a| + i\arg a.\tag{Q5}$$

Taking in account conditions $(3),$ one can get
\begin{align}
&\dfrac i2\left(\ln\dfrac{1-i\tan y}{-1+ip} - \ln\dfrac{1+i\tan y}{-1-ip}\right)
 = \dfrac i2\left(\ln\dfrac{1-i\tan y}{1+i\tan y} + \ln\dfrac{1+ip}{1-ip}\right)\\
& = \dfrac i2\left(-2iy + 2i\arctan p\right)
 = y - \arctan p.
\end{align}

Therefore, under the conditions $(3)$ can be used expression in the form of
$$J(p,y) = \dfrac i2 \left(\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{1+p\tan y}{1-ip}\right) 
- \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{1+p\tan y}{1+ip}\right)\right)
+ \left(y-\arctan p\right)\ \ln(1+p\tan y).\tag4$$

From $(1),(4),(Q1)$ should
$$I(1) = \dfrac{3\pi - 4\arctan3}{16}\ \ln\dfrac95
 - \dfrac14 F(p,t)\Bigg|_{t=-1}\phantom{|\hspace{-38mu}}^{\large\frac13}
\Bigg|_{p=-1}\phantom{|\hspace{-38mu}}^{\large\frac35},\tag5$$

where
$$F(p,t) = \dfrac i2 \left(\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{1+pt}{1-ip}\right) 
- \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{1+pt}{1+ip}\right)\right)
+ \arctan\dfrac{t-p}{1+pt}\ \ln(1+pt).\tag6$$

Finally,
$$\color{brown}{\boxed{\phantom{\bigg|\!}I_1\approx0.27442\,80145\,78530\ }}$$
(see also Wolfram Alpha [calculations of constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3pi-4arctan%203)%2F16%20ln%201.8) and [the final checking](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F4%20(i%2F2.%20(-Li_2((p%20t%20%2B%201)%2F(1%2Bi%20p))%20%2B%20Li_2((p%20t%20%2B%201)%2F(1-i%20p)))%20%2B%20(arctan%20t%20-%20arctan%20p)%20ln(p%20t%20%2B%201))%20.%7B-1,1,1,-1%7D%20%2B0.162691813095711-0.27442801457853,%20where%20t%20%3D%20%7B1%2F3,-1,1%2F3,-1%7D,%20p%3D%7B3%2F5,3%2F5,-1,-1%7D)).

[Numeric calculations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E2%20arctan%20x%20%2F%20(1%2B4x)%20dx) give the same result.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

Try$${x\over (1+4x)(1+a^2x^2)}={{-{4\over a^2+16}\over 1+4x}}+{{a^2x+4\over a^2+16}\over 1+a^2x^2}={1\over a^2+16}\left({{-{4}\over 1+4x}}+{{a^2x+4}\over 1+a^2x^2}\right)$$

Comment: Yep, but integrating $I'(a)$ back with respect to $a$ looks hopeless.

Answer (score 4):

When I tried to  simplify result, I found more elegant way to compute this integral.
We now that $\Im Log z= \phi=\arctan(\Im z/\Re z)$
Due to this I can rewrite the integral in more simple way
$$\int^{2}_{0}\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{1+4x}\mathrm dx=\Im \int^{2}_{0}\frac{\log(1+ix)}{1+4x}\mathrm dx $$
It can be rewrite through logarith and dilogarithm by linear changing variable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function
$$I=\frac{\Im}{4} \left(-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{16}{17}+\frac{4 i}{17}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{8}{17}+\frac{36 i}{17}\right)+\log \left(\frac{9}{17}-\frac{36 i}{17}\right) \log (1+2 i)\right) $$

I am not a specialist in the polylogarithm, probably the imaginary parts of polilogarithm can be simplified.

The result for with additional parameter $$ \frac{\Im}{4} \left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{4 i-8 a}{a+4 i}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{4 i}{a+4 i}\right)+\log \left(\frac{9 a}{a+4 i}\right) \log (1+2 i a)\right) $$

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, do the integration by parts and and decompose a denominator
$$
\begin{align*}
& \int_0^2 \frac{\tan^{-1} (a x)}{1+4x} dx \\ = &\ \dfrac{\log 3 \tan^{-1} (2a)}{2}-\frac{a}{4}\int_0^2 \frac{\log(1+4x)}{1+a^2x^2} dx\\ = &\  \dfrac{\log 3 \tan^{-1} (2a)}{2}-\frac{a}{8}\int_0^2 \log(1+4x)(\frac{1}{1+iax}+\frac{1}{1-iax}) dx
\end{align*}$$
The obtained integrals can be rewrote through the dilogarithm $\text{Li}_2$ functions. The result have the following form

$$
\begin{align*}
I(a)&= \dfrac{\log 3 \tan^{-1} (2a)}{2}+\frac{i}{8}\left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a-4 i}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{9 a}{a-4 i}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{a}{a+4 i}\right) \\ + \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{9 a}{a+4 i}\right)-\log (9) \log \left(\frac{8 a+4 i}{-a+4 i}\right)+ \log (9) \log \left(\frac{-8 a+4 i}{a+4 i}\right)\right)
\end{align*}
$$
I think this answer can be simplified, but I do not want to do it.

Comment: More suitable looks the common form of $\int_0^b \dfrac{\arctan x\,dx}{1+ax}$

Answer (score 3):

To calculate by series or to try to get a "closed form" ?

I think the best is to use here the following formula:

> $$\int\frac{\ln(x+z)}{x-a}\,dx = \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x+z}{a+z}\right) - \ln(x+z)~\text{Li}_1\left(\frac{x+z}{a+z}\right) + C$$

It’s $~\displaystyle\tan x = \Im\ln(1+ix) = \frac{\pi}{2} + \Im\ln(x-i)~$ and we can set $~\displaystyle(a,z):=(-\frac{1}{4},-i)~$ .

Then we get:

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^2\frac{\arctan x}{1+4x}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\int\limits_0^2\frac{dx}{1+4x} + \frac{1}{4}\Im\int\limits_0^2\frac{\ln(x-i)}{x-\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}\,dx$

$\displaystyle =\frac{\pi}{4}\ln 3 + \frac{1}{4}\Im\left(\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{8+i36}{17}\right) - \ln(2-i)~\text{Li}_1\left(\frac{8+i36}{17}\right) \right) $

$\displaystyle\hspace{1.8cm} - \frac{1}{4}\Im\left( \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{16+i4}{17}\right) - \ln(-i)~\text{Li}_1\left(\frac{16+i4}{17}\right) \right) $

---

Separation of real part and imaginary part:

$\displaystyle \ln(2-i) = \frac{\ln 5}{2} - i\arctan\frac{1}{2} \enspace , \enspace\enspace  \ln(-i) = -i\frac{\pi}{2}$

$\displaystyle \text{Li}_1\left(\frac{8+i36}{17}\right) = -\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{81}{17} + i\arctan 4 \enspace , \enspace\enspace  \text{Li}_1\left(\frac{16+i4}{17}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\ln 17 + i\arctan 4$

*Note:* $\enspace$ For calculations with $~x>0~$ we can use $\displaystyle ~~\arctan x = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan\frac{1}{x}~$  .

$\displaystyle A:=\Im\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{16+i4}{17}\right) = \Im\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{272}}{17}e^{i\arctan\frac{1}{4}}\right)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(k\arctan\frac{1}{4}\right)}{k^2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{272}}{17}\right)^k$

Using $~\displaystyle \text{Li}_2(z) = -\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) -\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2(-z)~$ we get:

$\displaystyle \Im\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{8+i36}{17}\right) = \Im\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{1360}}{17}e^{i\arctan\frac{9}{2}}\right) = B - \left(\ln\frac{\sqrt{1360}}{17}\right)\left(-\pi + \arctan\frac{9}{2}\right)$

with $\enspace \displaystyle B := \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin\left(k\arctan\frac{9}{2}\right)}{k^2}\left(\frac{17}{\sqrt{1360}}\right)^k$

$\displaystyle R := \pi\ln\frac{36}{17} + \left(\ln\frac{85}{81}\right)\left(\arctan\frac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\ln\frac{80}{81}\right)\left(\arctan\frac{2}{9}\right)$

$A\approx 0.54772569304105608037669001217295320069571309$

$B\approx 0.46231444614312936610749685795341278946044980$

$R\approx 2.36624661042409606268346795278249163083184498$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^2\frac{\arctan x}{1+4x}\,dx = \frac{R}{8} + \frac{B-A}{4} \approx 0.2744280145785303292681352055429263510451648$

Answer (score 2):

$\def\B{\mathrm{B}}$Here we find the value of the integral as an explicitly real sum with good convergence properties, equation (1) below.

Let $x=1+t$ so
$$I = \frac{1}{5} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\arctan(1+t)}{1+\frac{4}{5}t}dt.$$
But
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac 4 5 t} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k t^k
\quad\textrm{and}\quad
\arctan(1+t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k t^k,$$
where
$$a_k = (-4/5)^k,\,
b_0 = \frac \pi 4,
\textrm{ and }
b_k = (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\sin(k\pi/4)}{k2^{k/2}}
\textrm{ for }k\geq 1.$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac{1}{5} \int_{-1}^1 \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k t^k dt
= \frac{2}{5}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{c_{2k}}{2k+1},
\end{align*}
where
$$c_k = \sum_{j=0}^k a_{k-j} b_j$$
is the Cauchy product of $a_k$ and $b_k$.
This can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac \pi 8 \log 3 -
\frac 2 5 \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^{2k}
\frac 1 {2k+1} \left(\frac 4 5\right)^{2k-j} \frac{\sin(j\pi/4)}{j 2^{j/2}} \\
&= \frac \pi 8 \log 3 -
\frac 2 5 \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=\lceil j/2\rceil}^{\infty}
\frac 1 {2k+1} \left(\frac 4 5\right)^{2k-j} \frac{\sin(j\pi/4)}{j 2^{j/2}} \\
&= \frac \pi 8 \log 3 -
\frac 1 4 \sum_{j=1}^\infty
\underbrace{\left(\frac 5 4\right)^{j} \frac{\sin(j\pi/4)}{j 2^{j/2}}
\B({16}/{25};{1}/{2}+\lceil{j}/{2}\rceil,0)}_{d_j},
\end{align*}
where
$$\B(x;a,b) = \int_0^x t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-1}dt$$
is the incomplete beta function.
We then write the sum in the following way,
$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty d_j = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (d_{4n+1}+d_{4n+2}+d_{4n+3}+d_{4n+4}).$$
Note that $d_{4n+4}=0$.
By exploiting the properties of the incomplete beta function $d_{4n+1}+d_{4n+2}+d_{4n+3}$ may be combined.
In particular we use that
$$\B(x;a+1,b) = \B(x;a,b) - \frac{x^a(1-x)^b}{a}.$$
After some manipulation we find
\begin{align*}
I &= \frac \pi 8 \log 3
+ \frac{1}{128}\Phi(-1/4,2,3/4) \\
& \quad - \frac{5}{1024}\sum_{n=0}^\infty
(-1)^n \left(\frac{25}{32}\right)^{2n}
\frac{776n^2+790n+181}{(2n+1)(4n+1)(4n+3)} \\
&\hspace{15ex}\times\B(16/25;2n+3/2,0),\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $\Phi(z,s,\alpha) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty {z^n}/{(n+\alpha)^s}$ is the Lerch transcendant.
(Note that $\Phi(-1/4,2,3/4)\approx 1.703446578$.)
We define $I_N$ to be given by (1) with the replacement
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\rightarrow\sum_{n=0}^N$ and show some of the partial sums to ten decimal places below. 
$$\begin{array}{l|l}
N & I_N \\ \hline
 0 & 0.2687920302 \\
 1 & 0.2749812408 \\
 2 & 0.2743541958 \\
 3 & 0.2744394932 \\  
 4 & 0.2744260568 \\
 5 & 0.2744283699 \\ 
 6 & 0.2744279472 \\ 
 7 & 0.2744280278 \\
 8 & 0.2744280119 \\
 9 & 0.2744280151 \\ 
 10 & 0.2744280145 \\  
 11 & 0.2744280146 \\
 12 & 0.2744280146 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can not calculate this sum in the closed form. Besides, this series diverges from $n=80.$

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: I appreciate the close reading. See the claim at the top of the post. The series does not diverge. It is straightforward to show that $\mathrm{B}(16/25;2n+3/2,0)\le (2^7/5)(4/5)^{4n}/(36n+27)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,this integral seems hopeless from the point of view that we could get some simple closed form solution.

As a practical person who has to solve problems in real life where it is necessary to calculate not with great precision I use often the following approach (applied to given issue):

I'm trying to replace the integrand in the integral with a simpler expression so that the latter would differ as little as possible from the value of the original expression.

In this case I will replace $\arctan x$ with

$$\frac{\arctan 2}{26}x(23-5x)$$

The maximum deviation of this expression from $\arctan x$ in $[0,2]$ is less than $0.03$

Now, replacing $\arctan x$ in the integral with the expression I evaluate the integral and get

$$\frac{\arctan 2}{832}(308-97\ln 3)$$
The absolute error of this result is about $0.007$

This is even better result than expected.

Now, noting that $\arctan 2$ and $\ln 3$ are both very close to $1$ I simplify the result to $\frac{211}{832}$

The absolute error of this last is still satisfactory from a practical point of view (about $0.021$)

In similar manner it is possible quickly estimate many difficult integrals (often easier than numerical integration procedures)